# Can we have tabs in the app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tabs

One of the things that I most dislike about the Android app is that it doesn't have tabs.  That makes it very inconvenient to pay attention to more than one site.  For example, on Stack Overflow and Code Review I put `intags:mine is:q` into the search bar.  I can't very easily switch between the sites because I must either get to the other site from the side bar and retype my search term, or hit back until I finally find it.  Often, I hit back one too many times and end up needing to retype any way.  Sometimes, the back button just ignores where I was previously and goes right to my feed..  If I want to go right back to where I was, there is no forward button.  I must get the site from the side and retype my search term.  Tabs would fix this.  Sometimes I want to see something about a user.  I open up his profile page and just keep clicking.  If I want to get back to where I was, I need to ... keep ... ... hitting ... back.  Can there just be support for multiple tabs to fix all this?  I would suggest that you can switch between the tabs by swiping to the left or right.  It doesn't matter that the inbox goes away, because you can still access it by clicking the `0` at the top.  The left side bar also would go away, but that top bar doesn't have a lot on it ....  I realize that this is a big change, but I will not come back if you don't do it ... Well, I won't be as happy.

Comment: In my opinion, that won't happen. SE app is not a browser. Better request can be asking to preserve your last activity per site. For example, when viewing a question then switching sites and coming back, you will see this question instead of reaching the questions list. Or when searching and leaving to different site or closing the app, when opening it again or getting back to the site, you will see the search results again. This will make the app more like whatsapp, which of course "remember" all the chats you have.

Comment: Not a browser? Maybe not yet, but why should it not be one?